# Browser can't load PHP script, but terminal can?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I'm creating a smart home assistant, I tried using basic Chrome TTS, other apis, and then fell on the Google Cloud Platform Text To Speech WaveNet thingie. I used a PHP code example to make it put the audio into a file in a folder (named clips.)

When I try to run the PHP file in a browser, it does not work, but running it using the php command in Mac OS terminal does work and creates the file successfully with no errors.

I've tried using Node.js, but it didn't work because I needed to run the file from HTML page and I didn't want to expose my Google Cloud Platform API credentials.

```php
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");

if(!isset($_GET['text'])) {
  json_encode(array(
    "success" => "false",
    "error" => "missingPhrase"
  ));
}

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioConfig;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SynthesisInput;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\TextToSpeechClient;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\VoiceSelectionParams;

$textToSpeechClient = new TextToSpeechClient();

$input = new SynthesisInput();
$input->setText($_GET['text']);
$voice = new VoiceSelectionParams();
$voice->setLanguageCode('en-US-Wavenet-D');
$audioConfig = new AudioConfig();
$audioConfig->setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding::LINEAR16);

$number = 0;
$fi = new FilesystemIterator("clips", FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
foreach ($fi as $f) {
  $number = $number + 1;
}
$number = $number + 1;

$resp = $textToSpeechClient->synthesizeSpeech($input, $voice, $audioConfig);
file_put_contents("clips/" . $number . '.mp3', $resp->getAudioContent());

echo json_encode(array(
  "file_name" => 'clips/' . $number . ".mp3"
));

?>
```

The result of the code above results in the default chrome "This page isn’t working" non-sence.

PS, I looked at some other answers on Stack Overflow related to the problem I'm having and they did **NOT** solve my problem and didn't cover nearly the same issue.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: I'd suggest checking the server error logs, if it says "This page isn't working", which usually points to a 500 Internal Server Error. The only thing I can guess is that the path to the autoload file is not the same when you load it via the web. Try using an absolute path there, or relative to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: No, the error log isn't often kept in the script folder. Look in `/Applications/MAMP/logs/`

Comment: Hi @aynber, I found the error log. Here is what it had inside it. I made sure to clear the file, and attempt to load the page again, https://hastebin.com/ocoyomemuz.sql. It was in the MAMP folder. :)

Comment: Looks like it can't find the credentials. Make sure it's able to load your credential file. See the URL linked in your error message for more information.

Comment: Hey @aynber, I'm a bit confused of what to do.

Comment: Refer to the linked page, https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for details on configuring credentials. You can either provide it using an environment variable, as described in that document, or you can download a keyfile and pass it directly into your client: `new TextToSpeechClient(['credentials' => '/path/to/keyfile.json']);`

Comment: @jdp thanks for the help! It works flawlessly now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @jdp, I was able to solve it. I needed to link to the json file containing authorization credentials. It works now. :)

```
$textToSpeechClient = new TextToSpeechClient(['credentials' => 'credentials.json']);
```